# Angular2 Http Call not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular, typescript

**Context :**

Following several tutorials, I am testing authentication with Angular2 and JWT. I come with a component and a service :

```
app.component.ts
user.service.ts
```

App component (and template) contains the subscription to an observable that shows the user logged in status. The Observable item is kept in the user service, and changes (fine) when user logs in and out.

The authentication token is written in "localStorage" as "auth_token". It contains a validity value (time) that should force the user to login again after a time.

What I'd like to do is to CHECK the token validity on app init. First, I tried to do it from the user.service CONSTRUCTOR, then (fail), I tried to do it from ngOnInit in the app.component, then (fail again), I tried to do it on event call (click on a button) from the app component, but fails again!

**Some shortened code :**

```
//app.component.html
//...
    <a md-button class="app-icon-button" aria-label="checklogin" (click)="checkLogin()">
        <md-icon svgIcon="check"></md-icon>
    </a>
//...

//app.component.ts
//...
    checkLogin(){
        console.log('CHECK LOGIN FUNCTION');
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        if(token){
            console.log('TOKEN FOUND');
            this.userService.checkToken(token);
        }else{
            console.log('NO TOKEN FOUND');
        }
    }
//...

//user.service.ts
//...
    checkToken(token){
        console.log('CHECK TOKEN FUNCTION');
        console.log('TOKEN : '+token);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        return this.http
            .post(
                '/url/script.php',
                JSON.stringify(token),
                { headers }
            )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                console.log('SCRIPT RESULT : ');
                if(res.valid){
                    console.log('TOKEN IS VALID');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    console.log('TOKEN NOT VALID');
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
//...
```

I did skip the observable part, and subscription.

**Problem :**

The problem actually is that the app NEVER CALLS the script!

When I do click on the "checkLogin" button (when token exists),

```
console shows 'CHECK LOGIN FUNCTION',
console shows 'TOKEN FOUND',
console shows 'CHECK TOKEN FUNCTION',
console shows 'TOKEN : '****************************** (token),
```

But it never shows 'SCRIPT RESULT',
and when using firebug to check if the http call is done, there is NO CALL to the script.php. Looks like the this.http part is just ignored...

Thanks for reading/help

Answer (score 1):

Ajax call's which use `Observables` will work only if you have an `subscriber`.

So you need to `subscribe` to that `Observable`. It is an `Angular 2` feature. When you don't subscribe the `Observable`, it will never make that call.

And also you don't need to return anything from the subscriber, because you actually can't return anything.

```
this.userService.checkToken(token).subscribe((res) => {
   console.log('SCRIPT RESULT : ');
   if(res.valid) {
      console.log('TOKEN IS VALID');          
   } else {
      console.log('TOKEN NOT VALID');
   }
});

checkToken(token){
   console.log('CHECK TOKEN FUNCTION');
   console.log('TOKEN : '+token);
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
   return this.http
       .post(
           '/url/script.php',
           JSON.stringify(token),
           { headers }
       )
       .map(res => res.json());           
}
```

Comment: Well, I just want to get the result of the check login, and then it's done... Maybe my approach with an observable is not the best way to do it... It means that I'll have to "subscribe" to get the result, and "unsubscribe" just after receiving it?

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe

Comment: I already have a subscription to an observable supposed to show the login status anytime...

Answer (score 1):

Service starts working when subscription used only when consumer subscribe to output result, using `.subscribe` method.

You need: `this.userService.checkToken(token).subscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkToken()` method is returning an `Observable` that you need to `subsrcibe` to. An observable will never to execute unless it's subscribed to.

```
checkLogin(){
        console.log('CHECK LOGIN FUNCTION');
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        if(token){
            console.log('TOKEN FOUND');
            this.userService.checkToken(token).subscribe(result => {
               console.log(result); 
            }),
            error => { 
               console.log(error); 
            });
        } else {
            console.log('NO TOKEN FOUND');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried using `Postman` and try to call function you need?

Also, why do You need to validate a token if `angular2-jwt` can do this for You?

You can do just like this:

install `angular2-jwt` with `npm`.

Include in `app.module.ts`:

`import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';`

add to providers:

```
providers: [
    AUTH_PROVIDERS,
],
```

and for example `auth.service.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject }                                               from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod }           from '@angular/http';
import { Router }                                                           from '@angular/router';

import { Observable }                                                       from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Configuration }                                                    from '../../app.config';

import { RegisterViewModel }                                                from '../../model/viewModel/registerViewModel';
import { LoginViewModel }                                                   from '../../model/viewModel/loginViewModel';

import { tokenNotExpired, AuthHttp }                                        from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

private actionUrl: string; 

constructor(private _http: Http, private _config: Configuration, private _router: Router, private _authHttp: AuthHttp){
    this.actionUrl = _config.apiUrl;
}

register(user: RegisterViewModel){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    //Admin in this system can only register users. that is why auth
    return this._authHttp.post(this.actionUrl + '/Account/Register', JSON.stringify(user), { headers : headers })
        .do(response => {
            console.log(response.toString());
        });
}

login(user: LoginViewModel) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:56181/api/token', "username=" + user.userName + "&password=" + user.password + "&userId=" + user.userId, { headers : headers })
        .do(response => {
            if(response){
                let authResult = response.json();
                this.setUser(authResult);
                this._router.navigate(['']);
            }
        });
}

public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    //angular2-jwt has this function to check if token is valid
    return tokenNotExpired();
}

private setUser(authResult: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.id_token);
}

public logout(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    this._router.navigate(['']);
}
```

}

also remember that `angular2-jwt` has default name for token in `localstorage` as `id_token` or else you will have to use `angular2-jwt` help class to specify other token name.

You can check if it is working by simply doing this:

in `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent { 
constructor(private _auth: AuthService){
}
}
```

and in `app.component.html`:

```
 <li>
 <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="!_auth.isAuthenticated()">Login</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="_auth.logout()" *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated()">Log Out</a>
 </li>
```

also You can read a little bit documentation about it in:

https://auth0.com/blog/introducing-angular2-jwt-a-library-for-angular2-authentication/

Comment: I'm new to JWT tbh, I just made this sample to test jwt and authentication with angular2 following tutorials...

Comment: I will provide a simple example how to use `angular2-jwt`, a sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Okay, what about the "guards" system for "router", I use canActivate...? and where does your "setOrRemoveAdmin()" function come from...? :)